# Microsoft Edge: cursor not viewing in input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge

today i've encountered a strange issue in my application
in my login page i have simple username and password fields.
Ih chrome, safari, IE and firefox the page works fine, but in the Edge even if I click the input, the keyboard input is not working in any field
Only when i have selected a suggestion in autocomplete it seems that the input works, but when i change focus in the password (for example), the input and cursor remains in the previous field
In UI instead the focus is correct.

in other pages like forgot password etc ... UI works fine

I've read that this is sometimes the case with Angular, but in my case it is not present.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: i use simple asp.net web forms with bootstrap 3

Comment: You need to how some demonstrative code. If your using Angular you should add the corresponding tags to your question.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the topic and angular is installed in some other pages, but not here
i've edited the page with some other infos

Comment: Still, without code showing the problem this is likely not answerable.

Comment: It seems that I found the issue:
In the container "div", it was present a css directive user-select: none; that causes this only in Edge. In other browser all works fine :|